# Sampler in ProTools with Pitch Shift automation but no time correction

Tags: avid, pitch-shifting, sampler, automation

I'm working on an animation Projekt aboute Robots and they are moving a lot, so i would use servo samples for it.

Im thinking a lot, and the best way to modulate these samples with pitch without time correction. Naturally you could not do this on an insert point with a pitch plug-in, that's why i looking for a sampler plugin, wich i can pitch the sample MORE than 50 cents up and down without time correction like iZotope Iris or Kontakt. 
The last 2 examples are not god: in Iris you pitch it correctly but with an LFO, so you cant automate it, in Kontakt you can set the cents just + or -50, and its not enough. I need more than 1 semitone up and down. The semitone adjustment opportunity is not god because the resolution. Structure plugin it would be good, there you can set the fine tune but its correct the time unfortunately.

any suggestions? thanks in advanced:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I think I understand the problem now. When you control the pitch with the LFO you're controlling it directly with a signal which (operating at signal rate) has a massive range and resolution, so it can control the pitch very precisely. When you use the pitch-bend wheel or write any automation in Pro Tools you are essentially writing in MIDI information (0-127) and this is not enough resolution for you, ie the control is not fine enough. So if, like I suggested, you use the pitch bender over 2 octaves, you are actually moving through 0.19 of a semitone with each MIDI step.

Have I got it now?

If so, I don't think you're going to find a solution in Pro Tools. The problem is that everything still complies with that horribly antiquated standard known as MIDI. Personally, I think it's crazy that we're so attached to it when we have better things like [OSC](http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc).

Perhaps the only suggestion I have is to work outside of Pro Tools and create a palette of sounds to then import. I built a small app in Max/msp which is good at this sort of thing. Here's a video of me mangling a servo sample with it:

[youtube]rbQs2BB3odg[/youtube]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbQs2BB3odg&feature=youtu.be

I think you could get some fairly expressive servo noises out of it, then import those into Pro Tools. It's got a resolution of 0-2000, but it interpolates between this range so should sound pretty smooth. If you're interested, read more and download [here](http://sounddesignwithmax.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/tapehead-sample-playback-for-sound.html).

Comment: ++!!!44! awesome app Mark:) and it would be the BEST for me. im thinking, maybe max for live and rewire coud be give the opportunity to see the movie in the same time, but is a stand alone app.
and your absolutely right! the mindi resolution 127 is the problem, it does not matter howe big is my pitchband, i cant be good enough:/ Maybe the new midi standard....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you're asking.

But... Iris has two modes - you can choose either to re-sample (change pitch and playback length) or use Radius RT pitch shifting where the length of the sample is preserved across each key, but the pitch is altered. You can then pitch shift across the whole keyboard.

You can find it in the manual if you want to read more:

http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/iris/help/Iris%20English%20Help%20PDF.pdf

P34

Perhaps this helps?

Comment: no. I mean, if you push a note on your midi keyboard, and when the sample is playing (30 sec servo motor)  you pitch down and up the sample during the palying.

Comment: and of course when is set to Resample

Comment: How about using the pitch wheel on your keyboard - you can set it to bend over 2 octaves.

Comment: hmm, maybe, and i could draw it in pro tools to on a midi rack. i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Durham,

the pitchwheel working well in Iris, i can set up 24 semitones if i would and automate in ProTools with a midi track. THX, you save my day:)

Comment: Pleased it worked out for you. It's actually not a technique I've used before, but I can see how it could work well.. so thank you, I might need it in the future! 

Comment: hmm..no i realized, however i can set up the the band, but the resolution is still not enough! I try to move the pitch wheel with mouse first, but it sounds worth when i pitch with a midikeyboard.  i mean, if i twist the fine tune button is still more smoother.
so the best if i can find a sampler with wide finetune range. more the 1 semitone.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, did you try the Time Machine pro mode in Kontakt 5 ?

Comment: this option is change the speed without pitch as i understood.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample what i mean: 
https://soundcloud.com/bohitomi/servo-pitch-samples
i made it with Iris, and a pitch controlled by LFO and i control the LFO rate. So i would control a pitch like this.